# nested properties on a class instance

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to build a structure (i need to do it for jestjs, in order to stub a module) that allows me to access a method in the following way:

```
// I make an instance of a class
const myTest = new Test()
// I access a method in this way
const result = myTest.prop1.prop2.prop3.getAll()
```

A basic class would look like

```
class Test2 {
  constructor(){}

  //getter
  getAll(){
    return 'Salutes'
  }
}
```

And I can access getAll()

```
const myTest2 = new Test()
const result = myTest.getAll()
//in this way result contains a string (*salutes*)
```

So how can I add more properties in the middle? I found something, but in typescript... I need to do it in javascript

Comment: Does order matter? Depth? For instance, should `myTest.prop1.getAll()` also return `"Salutes"`? `myTest.prop1.prop2.getAll()`? Should `myTest` have a `prop3` or just a `prop1`?

Comment: I need to do that to build a stub, so order is important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you need exactly the structure you've specified, in `Test` you'd have to create the object and have any methods you need be arrow functions or bound functions (**if** they need to access information from the `Test` instance; your example didn't so it wouldn't matter whether they had the right `this`). For instance:

```js
class Test {
    constructor() {
        this.prop1 = {
            prop2: {
                prop3: {
                    getAll: () => {
                        return "Salutes";
                    },
                    getAll2() { // Also works
                        return "Salutes";
                    },
                    getAll3: function() { // Also works
                        return "Salutes";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

const myTest = new Test();
const result = myTest.prop1.prop2.prop3.getAll();
console.log(result);
console.log(myTest.prop1.prop2.prop3.getAll2());
console.log(myTest.prop1.prop2.prop3.getAll3());
```

Example of using information on the `Test` instance (it's the same except for the constructor parameter and `message` property):

```js
class Test {
    constructor(message) {
        this.message = message;
        this.prop1 = {
            prop2: {
                prop3: {
                    getAll: () => {
                        // `this` refers to the `Test` instance because
                        // this is an arrow function
                        return this.message;
                    }
                    // `getAll2` and `getAll3` wouldn't work because 
                    // they would get `this` based on how they're called
                    // (it would be the `this.prop1.prop2.prop3` object).
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// I make an instance of a class
const myTest = new Test("Salutes encore!");
// I access a method in this way
const result = myTest.prop1.prop2.prop3.getAll();
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve it without modifying the `Test2` class, you can use [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) class and define custom handler for `get` method:

```js
class Test2 {
  constructor(){}
  
  getAll(){
    return 'Salutes'
  }
}

let instance = new Test2();

const handler = {
  get: function(target, prop, receiver) {    
    if (['prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3'].includes(prop)) {
      return receiver;
    }
    return Reflect.get(...arguments);
  }
};

const proxy = new Proxy(instance, handler);

console.log(proxy.prop1.prop2.prop3.getAll());
console.log(proxy.prop7);
console.log(proxy.getAll());
```

Comment: I would tend to assume the order is important. This will give the same result for `console.log(proxy.prop1.prop2.prop3.getAll());` as for `console.log(proxy.prop3.prop2.prop1.getAll());`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder good question, my answer is based on assumption that the objective is only to build a stub, I will let OP decide if it helps or something else is needed

Comment: Yeah, it's not clear about that (either way). :-)